# Where does the WordPress stores pages' visits count

Tags: wordpress, statistics

I have a site built on WordPress 5.7.6, and using a theme called Voice

**I want to see where visit counts are stored in the database...**

I know that the posts are stored in **wp_posts**
I can see the following statistics tables:
**wp_statistics_pages**
[Sample of Statistics pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPzIs.png)
the post with the mentioned ID 77503 has more than 250 views
so I doubted this tabled
the table **wp_statistics_visitor_relationships** is empty

here are the available tables:
[WordPress Statistics tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MfQt.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the `wp_options` table under the `option_name` = `stats_cache`.  It's managed by JetPack.